# how to get upper word with conditon

Tags: python

I have this code, that prints the with vowels and prints the vowel.

How do I change it to print the word with the vowel upper? I tried and didnt get it.

I have this string, a sentence:

```py
mystring = 'hi my name is Liam my brother is Yali my sensei is Omer my mother is Yaarit and Or is very cute and smart'
names = ''
```

And this loop:

```py
_sum = 0
Vowels = ["i", "I", "o", "O", "u", "U", "e", "E", "a", "A"]
a = mystring.split(' ') 
for word in a:
    for char in word:
        if char in Vowels:
            print(char.upper())
            break
        print(word)
        _sum += 1
print("Vowels: %d" % _sum)
```

Thank you, appreciate that everyone.

Comment: `names = [word for word in mystring.split() if word[0].isupper()]`

Comment: doesnt work, i want that if the word contains a vowel print the word and capitalize the vowel

Comment: Use `for i in range(len(word))` so you can iterate through characters with an index, convert the word to a list using `list(word)` then you can replace each character necessary of the word and print it after joining the word back into one string using `"".join(word)`.

Comment: So you want code where, given a string, would print all the words with vowels in them, with all the vowels uppercase?

Comment: yes, and i cant get it.

Comment: That's all: `print(''.join(c.upper() if c in 'aeiou' else c for c in mystring))`. Your example string will output as "hI my nAmE Is LIAm my brOthEr Is YAlI my sEnsEI Is OmEr my mOthEr Is YAArIt And Or Is vEry cUtE And smArt".

Answer (score 0):

```
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
words = "Some Words blah blah blah hmm"
words = words.split()
for word in words:
    if any(vowel in word for vowel in vowels): #checks if there is a vowel in the word
        output = ""
        for char in word:
            if char in vowels:
                output += char.upper() # vowel, so uppercase
            else:
                output += char # not vowel, leave unchanged
        print(output)
```

Your original code ends in the middle of a word, once it finds a vowel.

And in the future, it's generally best to post sample inputs and desired outputs.

There is another option, which might be faster...

```
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
words = "Some Words blah blah blah hmm"
words = words.split()
for word in words:
    output = ""
    hasVowel = False
    for char in word:
        if char in vowels:
            hasVowel = True
            output+=char.upper()
        else:
            output+=char
    if hasVowel:
        print(output);
```